# Libgdx - Transparent color over texture

Tags: libgdx, drawing

I am attempting to tint a texture a color but I want the texture to show under the tint. For example, I have a picture of a person but I want to tint them a light green and not change the transparency of the actual person itself.

So far I have attempted to use the SpriteBatch method **setColor** which takes rgba values. When I set the alpha value to .5 it will render the tinting and the texture with that alpha value. Is there any way to separate the alpha values of the tint and the texture?

I know I could draw another texture on top of it but I don't want to have two draw passes for the one texture because it will be inefficient. If there's anyway to do it in raw OpenGL that'd be great too.

Answer (score 0):

You could draw it without the alpha right? The lighter the color overlay is the less it shows (by default its `Color.White`). So if you want to tint it slightly green you could use `new Color(.9f, 1f, .9f, 1f)` halfway would be `new Color(.5f, 1f, .5f, 1f)` and full green `new Color(.0f, 1f, .0f, 1f)`.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you described (alpha affects the whole sprite's transparency) is defined by the shader.

The simple way to deal with this is in @MennoGouw's answer, but this always darkens the image. If you want to avoid darkening, you must use a custom shader. You can use a shader that acts somewhat like the Overlay blend mode in photoshop.

Here's an overlay fragment shader you could combine with the vertex shader from SpriteBatch's default shader (look at its source code). Here you can set the tint with the `setColor` method. To control the tint, you need to blend toward white. This method allows alpha to be preserved for fading sprites in and out if you need to.

```
tmpColor.set(tintColor).lerp(Color.WHITE, 1f - tintAmount);
tmpColor.a = transparencyAmount;
batch.setColor(tmpColor);
```

-

```
#ifdef GL_ES
    #define LOWP lowp
    precision mediump float;
#else
    #define LOWP
#endif

varying vec2 v_texCoords;
varying LOWP vec4 v_color;

uniform sampler2D u_texture;

const vec3 one = vec3(1.0);

void main()
{
    vec4 baseColor = texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoords);
    vec3 multiplyColor = 2.0 * baseColor.rgb * v_color.rgb;
    vec3 screenColor = one - 2.0 * (one - baseColor.rgb)*(one - v_color.rgb);
    gl_FragColor = vec4(mix(multiplyColor, screenColor, step(0.5, baseColor.rgb)), v_color.a * baseColor.a);
}
```

Comment: This was similar to the solution I came up with. This was actually a double post but I forgot to delete this one and close it. I posted it on the Game Dev section and got an answer that I'll post below

Answer (score 0):

I found the simple solution to be

```
float light = .5f; //between 0 and 1
batch.setColor(light, light, light, 1);
batch.draw(...);
batch.setColor(Color.White);
```